# Dynamics of Honey in hot water: Honey accelerates like it is falling through air?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, home-experiment, viscosity, water

Here is a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnuDx8RsraU) showing the honey accelerating in the hot water. As you can see, there are also dynamics. Since the water started stationary, I guess the dynamics arise because of convection flow. What is the explanation for the fast acceleration?  It seems very counter-intuitive.

Is there a way to connect the heat equation and the Navier-Stokes equation, or is there an easier method? I also cannot say how to model the honey.  Is it a liquid or a solid?

[image: Honey flowing into hot water]

Comment: Can you please state more clearly what you're asking? There is no question in the body of this post, and the title question is vague.

Comment: ok chase, I will reformulate.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is that the honey is significantly denser than the surrounding water, so it's merely falling and breaking up/dissolving at the same time. Because of this instability the honey droplets form odd shapes and which then cause them to fall in paths which aren't straight (picture a leaf falling in air).

Here is an article about [fluid thread breakup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_thread_breakup) (WP) that happens to mentions honey, but that is in air and not hot water, where the dynamics are different.

**Edit:**
The viscosity of honey is temperature dependent, so as the honey warms up I would expect it's behaviour to change. You can also try pouring hot honey into hot water.

Comment: This seems reasonable, but I have to underline that the experiment will have a totally different outcome if the water is cold. I could upload it also, but I think it is obvious!

Comment: @varantir, you should upload it! It's not obvious to me...

Answer (score 1):

There may be the following mechanism of acceleration. When falling in a fluid, a body eventually reaches some stationary speed. This speed depends on the viscosity. Maybe the viscosity decreases as honey's temperature increases in hot water, so the stationary speed increases as well.